# Padding in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

In PyTorch tensor, I would like to obtain the output from the input as follows:

[image]

How can I achieve this padding in Pytroch?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not an example of a good question. A good question, requires a detailed description of the problem, coded examples of the current and previous attempts you have made, your current output and your desired output. Questions that are essentially, "Write my code for me." are not acceptable. See : [How to Ask A Good Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @cmprogram with the attached figure, I think this question is good enough.

Comment: @shai The question was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is

```
def my_odd_padding(list_of_2d_tensors, pad_value):
  # get the sizes of the matrices
  hs = [t_.shape[0] for t_ in list_of_2d_tensors]
  ws = [t_.shape[1] for t_ in list_of_2d_tensors]
  # allocate space for output
  result = torch.zeros(sum(hs), sum(ws))
  result.add_(pad_value)
  fh = 0
  fw = 0
  for i, t_ in enumerate(list_of_2d_tensors):
    result[fh:fh+hs[i], fw:fw+ws[i]] = t_
    fh += hs[i]
    fw += ws[i]
  return result
```

assuming all tensors on `list_of_2d_tensors` are of the same `dtype` and on the same `device` you may explicitly set this dtype and device to `result` when you allocate it using [`torch.zeros`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.zeros)

Comment: Using the above code I could pad the matrices that I want to achieve! In my case, the size of each matrix in the list is all the same.